# The given role or permission should use guard

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

I encountered this problem for which I do not know a solution
can you help me ??

i use  spatie permission

The problem is that when I do work `$team->assignRole($roleOwner)`it never recognizes the graud

when i create new project there is 4 roles default created

```
Project Controller 


$roleOwner = Role::create([
    'name' => $project->key . '_' . $project->user_id . '_' . 'owner',
    'key' => 'owner',
    'project_id' => $project->id,
]);
$roleAdmin = Role::create([
    'name' => $project->key . '_' . $project->user_id . '_' . 'admin',
    'key' => 'admin',
    'project_id' => $project->id,
]);

$roleMember = Role::create([
    'name' => $project->key . '_' . $project->user_id . '_' . 'member',
    'key' => 'member',
    'project_id' => $project->id,
]);

$roleViewer = Role::create([
    'name' => $project->key . '_' . $project->user_id . '_' . 'viewer',
    'key' => 'viewer',
    'project_id' => $project->id,
]);

$permissions = Permission::query()
    ->get();

$roleOwner->syncPermissions($permissions);
$roleAdmin->syncPermissions($permissions);
$roleAdmin->revokePermissionTo(['project-close']);
$roleMember->givePermissionTo([
    'issue-show',
    'issue-create',
    'issue-edit',
    'issue-delete',
    'issue-move-backlog',
    'issue-move-board',
    'issue-show-history',
    'comment-create',
    'comment-edit',
    'comment-delete',
]);
$roleViewer->givePermissionTo([
    'issue-show',
    'comment-create',
    'comment-edit',
    'comment-delete'
]);

$team = Team::query()
    ->create([
        'access' => true,
        'invite_status' => 'accept',
        'role_id' => $roleOwner->id,
        'project_id' => $project->id,
        'user_id' => $project->user_id
    ]);

$team->assignRole($roleOwner);
```

Role model

```
class Role extends Model implements RoleContract
{
    use HasPermissions;
    use RefreshesPermissionCache;

    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $guard_name = 'customer';

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $attributes['guard_name'] = $attributes['guard_name'] ?? config('auth.defaults.guard');

        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->guarded[] = $this->primaryKey;
    }
```

Unit test

```
public function test_success_story()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create([
        'email' => fake()->email,
        'identify_number' => fake()->uuid(),
    ]);
    RequestHistory::factory()
        ->create([
            'identify_number' => $user->identify_number,
            'expired_at' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(15)
        ]);

    $this->postJson('/register-complete', [
        'identify_number' => $user->identify_number,
        'name' => 'mohammedMaher',
        'password' => 'MyPassword123',
        'password_confirmation' => 'MyPassword123'
    ]);

    $originalPhotoPath = 'upload/projects_icon/test.png';
    $newIconName = 'test-2.png';
    $destinationPath = 'upload/projects_icon/' . $newIconName;
    Storage::disk('public')->copy($originalPhotoPath, $destinationPath);
    $name = fake()->name;

    $response = $this->postJson('api/projects/create', [
        'name' => $name,
        'key' => substr($name, 0, 2),
        'icon' => new UploadedFile(storage_path('app/public/' . $destinationPath), $newIconName, null, null, true),
    ]);
    $response->assertStatus(201);
}
```

The error test

Expected response status code [201] but received 500.

Failed asserting that 201 is identical to 500.

The following exception occurred during the last request:

Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\GuardDoesNotMatch: The given role or permission should use guard `` instead of `customer`. in C:\xampp\htdocs\all_laravel\taskat-backend\vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Exceptions\GuardDoesNotMatch.php:12